# Enterprise library logging block doesn't log

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I installed Enterprise Library 6 via NuGet and then used the Enterprise Library Configuration Application Block Console to set up logging to rolling flat file and event log.

I then created a static class to do the logging:

```
public static class LoggerBlock {
    public static void Write(string message, string category, int priority, int eventID, TraceEventType severity)
    {
        LogWriter logWriter = new LogWriterFactory().Create();
        Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriter, false);
        logWriter.Write(message, category, priority, eventID, severity);
        logWriter.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
LoggerBlock.Write("Job executed...", "Information", 2, 1, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information);
```

I've stepped through the code and can verify that `LoggerBlock.Write` is executing and no exception is being thrown. However no log file is generated and nothing ends up in the event log either.

What am I missing?

EDIT - Here's the App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="MyLog.log" formatter="Text Formatter"
        rollInterval="None" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Still trying to solve this? I created a simple console app and it wrote a RollingFlatFile.log as expected. I took **the config** (only) from [logging-block-in-microsoft-enterprise-library-6-0](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/logging-block-in-microsoft-enterprise-library-6-0/).

Comment: Just curious, is there a `Dispose` or `Flush` method on the `LogWriter`? Wondering if those have to be explicitly called for the content to be written to the sinks (file, database, etc.). Also can you share the configuration file you have for this?

Comment: And one more thing to check, is if the configuration file is set to copy to the output directory on build.

Comment: @ajawad987 you can take a look at the source [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/logging-application-block/blob/master/source/Src/Logging/LogWriter.cs)

Comment: @ajawad987 There was a Dispose method which I tried calling, but it didn't have any effect. I've added the app.config as per your request.

Comment: I wrote to the `MyLog.log` successfully by adding `<listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>` to the app.config. I will write everything in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write the log file by adding

```
<listeners>
   <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
</listeners>
```

To the `<allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">` section.

Here's my code (console app):

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ELogging
{
    internal static class LoggerBlock
    {
        private static readonly LogWriter LogWriter;

        static LoggerBlock()
        {
            LogWriter = new LogWriterFactory().Create();
            Logger.SetLogWriter(LogWriter, false);
        }

        public static void Write(string message, string category, int priority, int eventId, TraceEventType severity) => LogWriter.Write(message, category, priority, eventId, severity);
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoggerBlock.Write("Job executed...", "Information", 2, 1, TraceEventType.Information);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and my App.config (yours with the adding):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" 
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
           log="" machineName="." 
           traceOutputOptions="None" />

      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" 
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           fileName="MyLog.log" formatter="Text Formatter"
           rollInterval="None" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}"
           name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

After this the `bin\Debug\MyLog.log` was created successfully:

---

Timestamp: 21/12/2018 11:29:32

Message: Job executed...

Category: Information

Priority: 2

EventId: 1

Severity: Information

---

Check it out.